# how to configure FreeRADIUS to proxy the PAP request inside an EAP-TTLS tunnel

Tags: freeradius

how can I configure FreeRADIUS to proxy the PAP request inside an EAP-TTLS tunnel?
Client sends a EAP-TTLS with PAP as inner protocol to freeradius server. I want to proxy the PAP request to another RADIUS server which understands only PAP. How could I configire freeradius for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure in the eap module configuration

```
proxy_tunneled_request_as_eap = no
```

Configure your proxy realm in `proxy.conf`

Set proxy realm in inner server

```
update control {
    Proxy-To-Realm := <realm>
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, could you mark as solved? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just putting the solution steps in case someone needs it.

1. Add realm in proxy conf file (/sbin/proxy.conf):
   realm  MYAUTH {
       type            =  radius
       authhost        = Radius_server_IP:Port]
       secret          = RadiusSharedSecret
       nostrip
   }
2. Modify virtual server information in /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap.conf:
   ttls{
       .........
       .........
       virtual_server = "proxy-inner-tunnel"
   }
3. In /etc/raddb/sites-enabled creates a softlink 
   proxy-inner-tunnel  pointing to /etc/raddb/sites-available/proxy-inner-tunnel. 
   Modify proxy-inner-tunnel to add the proxy realm:
   authorize {
       update control {
           &Proxy-To-Realm := "MYAUTH"
       }
   }