# how can I configure FreeRADIUS to proxy the PAP request inside an EAP-PEAP-GTC tunnel?

Tags: freeradius

how can I configure FreeRADIUS to proxy the PAP request inside an EAP-PEAP-GTC tunnel? . I want to proxy the PAP request to another RADIUS server which understands only PAP. How could I configire freeradius for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to configure FreeRADIUS to proxy the PAP request inside an EAP-TTLS tunnel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864953/how-to-configure-freeradius-to-proxy-the-pap-request-inside-an-eap-ttls-tunnel)

Comment: It is working for EAP-TTLS but for EAP-PEAP-GTC, only username is proxied to target server and the password is NOT sent.

Comment: What attributes are present in the innter tunnel request?

Comment: only user-name is present in inner tunnel. We want to send user-name and user-password to another radius server which only understands PAP.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your proxy realm in `proxy.conf`

Call the eap module in the authorize section of the inner tunnel, and if the EAP module creates the User-Password attribute during the round, proxy the request.

```
authorize {
    eap
    if (&User-Password) {
        update control {
            Proxy-To-Realm := <realm>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not proxy the request to the target server.

Comment: It should do.  If it doesn't you've either not configured the realm correctly, or it's a bug in the code.  Could you provide your proxy.conf file and the debug output with ``radiusd -X`` via something like pastebin.

Comment: inner-tunnel at pastebin.com/52DvKnSW

Comment: Thanks.  After investigating this a bit further, it seems that the code does not allow this to work.  Instead of exposing the password from GTC as an attribute for rlm_pap to pickup, the rlm_eap_gtc module it executes the authentication section of the current virtual server.

I can fix this if you're willing to test using the v3.1.x branch.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. We can test using the v3.1.x branch. Let us know when I can test this.

Comment: Can you please provide a timeline for the fix.

Comment: Is this being fixed in upcoming version 3.1